# How to get entity or pass variable to Symfony2 twig form widget?

Tags: forms, variables, twig, symfony-2.1

In my *edit.html.twig* I have:

```
{% form_theme edit_form 'MyBundle:Entity:form.html.twig' %}
{% set img_src = asset('120x100.jpg') %}
{{ dump(img_src) }}
{{ dump(entity) }}
{{ form_widget(edit_form, {'form_type': 'horizontal', 'img_src': img_src }) }}
```

There I have **img_src** and **entity** dumped with no problem.
In *form.html.twig* I have:

```
{% extends 'MyBundle:Form:bootstrap.html.twig' %}
{% block _entity_field_widget %}
    {{ dump(img_src) }}
    {{ dump(entity) }}
    {% set type = 'hidden' %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endblock _channel_media_widget %}
```

*bootstrap.html.twig* is just a bootstraped *form_div_layout.html.twig*
And in that widget I have no **img_src** nor **entity**.
Any ideas how to get entity in widget? Should it be passed to form widget or is there another way? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each symfony form type extents AbstractType class.

AbstactType class has method:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->set('img_src', '120x100.jpg');
    $view->set('my_variable', $foo);

}
```

You can create this method on your form type and next in your twig:

```
{{ asset(img_src) }}
```

Comment: It still gives me _Variable "entity" does not exist_. In controller: `$editForm = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity, array('em' => $em, 'entity' => $entity));`. In EntityType setDefaultOptions method: `$resolver->setRequired(array('entity'));` and in BuildView method: `$view->vars['entity'] = $options['entity'];`. In form theme block __entity_field_widget_ {{ dump(entity) }}. What did I miss? (Dumped $options['entity'] - it's what I need)

Comment: View variables are visible only on current form level - where are declared. In parent widgets like "entity_field" try to use form.parent.vars.entity, form.parent.vars.img_src

Comment: @DanielKorsak Thanks for `form.parent.vars.*`. That's what I was actually looking for when I found this question.

Comment: As of 2.3.7 you have to use $view->vars

Comment: I think that this answer should be completed with what @NateBundy wrote.