# Twig : Access to variable from outer scope in a form widget customization

Tags: scope, block, twig, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to customize a specific widget, like in the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field

The problem is that in this custom block, I need to use a variable from my actual template. I thought *"blocks have access to variables from outer scopes"*, but apparently not in this case :

```
{% extends "CDASvBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block _contact_activity1_widget %}
<select name="contact[activity1]">
    {% for key, child_contact_categories in contact_categories_tab %}
    <option value="{{key}}">{{child_contact_categories}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**It's saying that `contact_categories_tab` is undefined, but outside of this block (in the normal `content` block for example), it works !**

I tried something like :

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' with contact_categories_tab as contact_categories_tab %}
```

But that doesn't either.. Though I'm not sure I understand if I have to use `use` and how !

I see one other solution that I haven't tried yet : put this customization in another template. But I don't really want to do that (few lines in a new template), there should be a way to do that in only **ONE template** ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer in a previous post :

> Each symfony form type extents AbstractType class.
>
> AbstactType class has method:
>
> ```
> public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
> {
>     $view->set('img_src', '120x100.jpg');
>     $view->set('my_variable', $foo);
>
> }
> ```
>
> You can create this method on your form type and next in your twig:
>
> ```
> {{ asset(img_src) }}
> ```

**Source : [How to get entity or pass variable to Symfony2 twig form widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767837/how-to-get-entity-or-pass-variable-to-symfony2-twig-form-widget)**